# Can I associate a swift class with LauchScreen.xib file

Tags: ios, swift, xib, launch

Can I associate a swift class with LauchScreen.xib file, if yes can someone please tell how

Because when I try to do it, it does not show up in the dropdown/auto complete

Answer (score 2):

You can't do anything like that.

The launch screen xib or storyboard isn't something that is run when your app starts.  Xcode simply uses it to generate the pngs for launch images at all supported device sizes and orientations when your app is compiled.

Have a look in your app bundle and you'll see these generated images..